# Laravel 6 Error: Multi select value not going to next page

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-6

I've been stuck in it for a while. I'll try to explain it in detail for a better understanding. I'm using **multiple** select to fetch multiple values in the select field. The issue is that if I write **required** keyword in it, it doesn't submit the form. And if I remove the **required**, the value is not sent to the next page.

**Form**

```php
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="user-name" class="col-form-label">{{ __('Assign To') }}</label>
    <select name="user_name[]" id="user_name" style="width:100%;"
            class="form-control chosen-select" multiple="multiple"
            placeholder="Enter Users...">
        <!--  <option disabled value="">{{ __('Select User') }}</option> -->.
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is the **js** code:

```
    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
$('button').click(function(){
        $(".chosen-select").val('').trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
```

**Controller** (where the value is fetched)

```php
public function assign_proj(Request $request)
{
    $pro = new ProjectsAssignedtoUser;
    $pro->Project_ID = $request->input('project_name');
    $pro->Project_Name = DB::table('projects')
        ->where('Project_Number', '=', $pro->Project_ID)->value('Project_Title');
    $User_IDs[] = $request->input('user_name');
}
```

The issue is with the form, the controller code is optional. I have no idea why the form data from the multi-select field is not forwarding to the controller. Any suggestions, solutions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I tried your code and it is working fine. I am getting the **selected** username in controller

Comment: I've added the 'chosen-select' class for selecting fields using JQuery. Here is the link:
https://jsfiddle.net/esedic/Da4m3
Maybe this is causing the issue..

Comment: I have implemented `chosen-select.` Still your code is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Sehdev for your time. I just found the issue and resolved it. In the js code, the second line was resetting the data of that field.

```
$('button').click(function(){
        $(".chosen-select").val('').trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
```

Due to this code, the data in that **select** field was getting reset and thus getting empty. As I commented this, the issue was resolved.